# Database Query in Sailsjs / Waterline

Tags: database, sails.js, waterline

Suppose I have the 'User' model which has an attribute 'age' which can be set or not. I have 3 users A, B and C:

> A: { age: 20 },
>
> B: { age: 10 },
>
> C: {}

With Sails I want to select all users which have a minimum age of 15 and at the same time include all users with unspecified age. In this case the query would return A (since age > 15) and C (since age is unspecified).

I have yet to find I way to issue such a query. From what I have gathered it should look something like:

```
var searchConditions = {
  age: { 
    or: [
      { '>': 15 },
      { '==': 'undefined' },
    ]
  }
}
Users.find(searchConditions, function foundUsers(err, users) { //... });
```

This is obviously not right though.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you default the age to -1 and then retrieve all users with age -1 along with those with age >15 ?

Comment: this is what I did after all, although I'm not entirely happy with the solution as it will have to be ported to other filter values in which there might not be a value which would signify 'null' or 'missing'. however it's the best thing so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to say:

```
{'==': null}
```

Comment: Does not work. In the database the value is not null, it's simply missing. At the same time while declaring my model's attribute as an integer I cannot default it to null. More specifically Sails doesn't allow me to do this:

age: { type: 'integer', defaultsTo: null }

Comment: There's no such thing as a "missing" database value. If the field is there, it **always** has a value, even if it's null. If you're trying to check for the existence of the field itself, I don't know of a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to sum things up, what I would have done for that particular query would have been (solution also hinted by user3350692):

```
var searchConditions = {
  or: [
    { 
      age: { '>': 15 }
    },
    { age: -1 }
  ]  
}
Users.find(searchConditions, function foundUsers(err, users) { //... });
```

and on the User model I wpould have the age property:

```
age: { type: 'integer', defaultsTo: -1}
```